# Calculate the probability that $x \lt 5$ given Poisson distribution states the mean is $6$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Two grocers agree that the daily demand for a particular item has Poisson distribution. However, grocer $A$ claims that the mean demand is $3$ items per day, while grocer $B$ claims that the mean demand is $6$ items per day.

They agree to resolve the disagreement by observing the demand on one particular day: $B$ agrees to
accept $A$’s claim if the observed demand is $4$ or less, and $A$ agrees to accept $B$’s claim if the observed demand
is $5$ or more.

(a) Calculate the probability that $A$’s claim is accepted when, in fact, $B$’s claim is correct

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried? Do you know the probability distribution function (or cumulative distribution function) for a Poisson random variable with mean 6?

Comment: does a PMF include the summation sign before it or is it purely just the equation?

Comment: is the answer 0.134 or 0.283 to 3d.p

Comment: Well, let $X$ be the observed demand on a given day. We know that $X$ has a Poisson distribution with mean 6, so that $$\operatorname{Pr}(X=x)=\begin{cases}\frac{6^xe^{-6}}{x!} & \text{for nonnegative integers }x\\0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ You want $$\operatorname{Pr}(X\le 4)=\sum_{x=0}^4\operatorname{Pr}(X=x).$$

Comment: and do i allow gamma equal 6? and then just sum all values from 0 to 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the observed demand. The problem states that $X$ is [Poisson distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) random variable with mean of $6$ items per day. Denote $X(\omega)$ the actual observed value of the demand, also known as realization of the random variable $X$.

The A's claim is accepted if $X(\omega) \leqslant 4$. The probability of this event is
$$
   \Pr\left(X \leqslant 4\right) = \sum_{n=0}^4 \Pr(X=n)
$$
Can you finish this off?